# how to get python to print different responses to similar input

Tags: string, loops

I need python to go through a list of names and print the following:
first time it sees a name it prints "welcome name" (got that)
second time it sees a name it prints "welcome back name".
What I have so far is that if the name appears more than once, it will be appended to a second list. How can I get python to print welcome the first time it sees the name and welcome back the second?

```
guests=input("What are the names of the guests? ")
guests=guests.split(",")
m=()
for i in guests:
  if guests.count(i)>1:
   m.append(i)
        for i in m:
   else:
    print ("Welcome, ", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think this is what you are looking for

```
guests=input("What are the names of the guests? ")
guests=guests.split(",")

other = []

for person in guests:
  if person in other:
    print('Welcome back, ', person)
  else:
    print('Welcome, ', person)
    other.append(person)
```

If I put in the names:

```
craig, smith, smith, john, sarah, vicky, jenny, john
```

The output is:

```
Welcome, craig
Welcome, smith
Welcome back, smith
Welcome, john
Welcome, sarah
Welcome, vicky
Welcome, jenny
Welcome back, john
```

Comment: If this is answer you are looking for, please make sure to vote it as an answer or comment to get further assistance